# strtok_r tokens with delimiters

Tags: c, strtok

I've found similar posts, but no clear answers to my questions about `strtok_r`.

I'm using `strtok_r` to parse a command line to get commands I need to execute via execv with flags, however, for testing purposes, I print out. When trying to delimit multiple characters, excluding whitespace, it works fine. But when testing for whitespace, using the code below:

```
void tokenize(char *str1)
{
  char *token;
  char *saveptr1;
  int j, i;


  const char *delim = " ";
  i = strlen(str1);

  for(j = 0; j < i; j++, str1 = NULL)
  {
    token = strtok_r(str1, delim, &saveptr1);
    if(token == NULL)
      break;

    printf("save: %s\n", token);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I get the following output for a test string (`ls -al`):

```
save: ls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you read the string?
Maybe you are reading the string with something like: cin >> string; or scanf("%s", str); that only read the first token("ls").

Instead youd should read the entire line with something like cin.getline() or scanf("%[^\n]", str). Check that!

Why strtok_r istead of strtok?

Comment: I read in from the command line using scanf, but I don't understand what the scanf you wrote does. Also, strtok_r since I have to track for other commands that affect process creation and order

Comment: if your input is: "ls -al" and use scanf("%s", str), scanf reads only "ls".
scanf("%[^\n]\n", str) = read entire line, read while not reach end of line (^\n), maybe you prefer use gets() that reads a line and not only a string.

Comment: I get the correct full line now using that scanf you suggested, however, I'm hanging until another line of entry is entered, then the program executes and prints. Do you think it would be better to run a gets loop instead?

Comment: Try with scanf("%[^\n]", str): remove last '\n'.

There exist a controversial question about using gets(), in deed, is not recommended.

Comment: that was the problem, didn't need the extra \n character, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is setting `str1=NULL` after each time through the loop

```
for(j = 0; j < i; j++, str1 = NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

so the first time through the loop, it works as you would expect, but after that, no further tokens are extracted because `str1` doesn't point to the string any more.